# ¿Por que mi codigo concatena los números en vez de sumarlos?

Tags: javascript

Quiero hacer una calculadora simple que sume los datos que le coloco, pero en vez de sumarlos, concatena los números, es una solución simple lo sé, pero soy nuevo en esto de la programación y no doy con lo que tengo que modificar para que sume mis números en vez de concatenarlos.

```
function suma( nro1, nro2) {
        var nro1 = nro1
        var nro2 = nro2
        var nro3 = nro1 + nro2
        return nro3;
    }

    var valone
    var valtwo

    alert('ingrese los numeros a sumar');
     valone = prompt();
     valtwo = prompt();
    alert( suma(valone,valtwo));
```

Comment: Necesitas identificarlos como tipo number, para eso pásalos como argumento de parseInt(), parseFloat() segunda el caso o como argumento del constructor Number

Comment: Puedes realizarlo de esta forma: var nro1 = parseInt(nro1);, ya que por defento el var nro1 guarda los datos de forma cadena o String

Answer (score 5):

Al ser `Strings` y usar el carácter `+`  los valores se concatenan no se suman.

```js
function suma2() {
   var nro1 = document.querySelector("#val1").value;
   var nro2 = document.querySelector("#val2").value;
   var nro3 = +nro1+(+nro2);//Esto hace el truco, para sumar strings
   var result2 = parseInt(nro1) + parseInt(nro2);//Usando parseInt
   //return nro3;
   document.querySelector("#result").value = nro3;
   document.querySelector("#result2").value = result2;
}

/*
function suma() {
   var nro1 = nro1;
   var nro2 = nro2;
   var nro3 = nro1 + nro2;
   return nro3;
}

    var valone
    var valtwo

    alert('ingrese los numeros a sumar');
     valone = prompt();
     valtwo = prompt();
    alert( suma(valone,valtwo));
  */
```

```html
Num 1<input type="text" id="val1"/>
Num 2<input type="text" id="val2"/>
<button onclick="suma2()">Sumar</button>
<br/>
<br/>
Result 1
<input type="text" id="result"/>
<br/>
<br/>
Result 2 - ParseInt
<input type="text" id="result2"/>
```

**Update:**

Referente al `parseInt()`, `parseFloat()` son métodos que se usan en Javascript para convertir de `string` a `int` y de `string` a `float`.

`parseInt()`: Recibe un valor `string` y lo convierte a `Integer`

`parseFloat()`: Recibe un valor `string` y lo convierte a `Float`

Si no tiene sentido la explicación anterior, entonces es necesario que aprendas primero los tipos de datos que existen en JavaScrit y en muchos lenguajes de programación:

**string** = Es una cadena de caracteres, por *default* cualquier valor que tomes de los controles `HTML` será tipo `string`.

Cuando el usuario pasa como valor `1` par el sistema en realidad esta tomando el valor `"1"`

entonces

`"1" + "2"`  <-- Ese  `+` concatena porque ambos campos son `string` y da como resultado `"12"`

Al usar `parseInt()` convertirá los números `string` a valores enteros

`1 + 2`  <--- Donde el compilador identifica ambos datos como numéricos y realiza la suma dando como resultado `3` de tipo `int`.

**Int** = Int hace referencia a los valores Enteros, que serian los números sin punto decimal o punto flotante.  Claro que `int` tiene un limite y es diferente en cada lenguaje.

**Float** = Float hace referencia a los valores con punto flotante, que serian los números con punto decimal o punto flotante.

Ejemplo:

```
var num1 = 1;     //Representa un int
var num2 = 2;     //Representa un int
var result = 1/2; //Result sera convertido automáticamente a float: 0.5
```

Es una explicación muy simple, para mas detalle recomiendo que heches un vistazo a los siguiente temas:

1. [JavaScript basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics)
2. [Tipos de datos primitivos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)
3. [Data structures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, tiene sentido pero no sé usar el parse int aún.

Comment: Hola rodman, para futuras ocasiones recuerda comentar la respuesta si quieres expresar tu agradecimiento en lugar de publicar una respuesta, en cuanto a la respuesta, me parece correcta ya que te está indicando como resolver el problema, pero si aun tienes dudas mira como utilizar [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt) o [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number) en la MDN, un saludo y bienvenido.

Comment: Hola @Rodman99 no te preocupes si aun no has aprendido algo :-), amplie un poco la respuesta.  Parse = significa convertir de un tipo a otro, si no tiene sentido parseInt entonces necesitas estudiar un poco tipos de datos y como convertir entre tipos de datos, agregue algunos links a una documentación muy buena de JavaScript, vale la pena revisarlo y replicar los ejemplos te ayudara mucho en tu aprendizaje.